# Discord.js guildMemberAdd Get Guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How can I get the Guild ID from the guildMemberAdd event being fired in discord.js?

Checked the discord.js documentation but couldn't find anything about getting the Guild, just the member.

Comment: The [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) contains a `.guild` property.

Comment: And the `.guild` property has an `.id` property. So `client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => console.log(member.guild.id))`

Answer (score 1):

Use [GuildMember.guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=guild)

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
let { guild } = member //guild is now the member's guild
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use <GuildMember.guild> 
Example:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   let guild = member.guild;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get guild id using member.guild.id

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  const guildID = member.guild.id
  const guildName = member.guild.name
})
```